# Jest matchers to check given set of special characters not available in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to validate a string in which i have to check the not allowed special characters. if it contains not allowed special characters test case should fail. I tried matcher but it only accepts one args. I have a many not allowed special characters(eg:['@','`','!']). Is there any jest matcher in which i can pass array and check whether the array elements are not available in a string?

Matcher

```
expect(element[keys]).toEqual(expect.not.stringContaining('@'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using regex

```
sampleRegex=/[`~@$%^}[\]{|<>]/
expect('sampleString').toEqual(expect.not.stringMatching(sampleRegex));
```

Comment: `expect('samlestring').not.stringMatching(sampleRegex);`

Comment: may you provide some example?

Comment: sorry i could not provide you example as i am working with database. but on continuous run your matcher is not stable.

Comment: you can refer official docs here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectnotstringmatchingstring-regexp

Comment: @skyboyer i have another doubt to match min and max length in same matcher instead of using   
expect(element[keys].length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(values.min);                    expect(element[keys].length).toBeLessThanOrEqual(values.max);

Comment: it can be part of regexp as well:
`expect('samplestring').stringMatching(/^[^`~@$%^}[\]{|<>]{2,5}$/)`